# How to use did in statements?

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

Can we use 'did come' in statements instead of 'came', like this sentence:

> She did come from Italy.

Answer (score 6):

In present-day English auxiliary *do* is used affirmatively only as a strongly stressed emphatic, typically to contradict a previous negation or to express a marked contrast with a previous assertion:

> A: Carla's from Italy.
>   B: Carla, didn't come from Italy, I've known her practically my entire life, and she hasn't got a trace of an accent.
>   A: Yes she ***did*** come from Italy—but she was less than a year old when she left. She doesn't have an accent, but she ***does*** speak Italian at home.